# "No longer could I wait": Valid construction?

Tags: sentence, semantics, construction

> A lack of capital and experience had always kept me from pursuing this dream, but no longer could I wait.

I'm unsure whether or not the *no longer could I wait* fragment is correct. I have just written an essay for college application, and I'm hoping that someone may give their thoughts.

Comment: Regarding your second request -- ELU is not intended to be used for proofreading.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, ok.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically correct, if somewhat dramatic.

Comment: I opted for "I couldn't wait any longer." I do have a bit of a dramatic writing style, haha. Thank you for the response.

Comment: It's all there in your name, LOL :-) This is a great resource for people who want to speak/write well. Good luck w/essay.